# Create Sub Domain Issue

Tags: php, hosting

i'm creating subdomain name: abc.example.com. but when i write  abc.example.com then it's go to http://abc.example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi.

But Why ? It's should be show my Index page. Any idea or Solution?
Thanks.

Comment: You will need to ask your hosting provider. This is nothing that can be answered without knowing more about the server setup

Comment: Appears to be this issue: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/parked-domain-redirecting-cgi-sys-defaultwebpage-cgi-183171.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your hosting provider normally has an area where you designate the target directory in your admin panel.  you will need to find this and point this subdomain then upload your work files into this folder. 
remember that it can take up to 24 hours in some cases to propagate

Comment: Well@t q. Normally my root folder is /home/example. I upload all file to this folder which is related to the example domain. Then i create sub domain name abc.example.com. So it's show the root folder is public_html/abc SO.. I HAVE TO UPLOAD ALL FILE TO ABC FOLDER, RIGHT? AND I DID THIS...

Comment: you would want to place this folder where it is not accessible from your other domain